# Issue with - uninitialized constant WebDriver (NameError)

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir, browserstack

Hello and thanks in advance ...

I am trying to start browserstack and I am getting the following error:

```
 uninitialized constant WebDriver (NameError)
```

I am not sure how to resolve this...
My Code is below:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'

include Selenium

caps = WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new
caps[:os] = "Windows"
caps[:name] = "Watir WebDriver"
caps[:browser] = "firefox"
caps[:browser_version] = "50"
caps["browserstack.debug"] = "true"

browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote,
                             :url => "xxx",
                             :desired_capabilities => caps)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

watir-webdriver is deprecated, please install the latest version of WATIR, and then `require 'watir'`. WATIR is using `selenium-webdriver` inside now.

Answer (score 0):

`require 'watir-webdriver'` [is deprecated](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/master/lib/watir-webdriver.rb), and you should use `require 'watir'` going forward.

The `Capabilities` class has moved to [`Watir::Capabilities`](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/e8dd0c2104c2ac2d5c22c31053792ee50b704215/lib/watir/capabilities.rb).  The initialization and option keys look to be updated from what you are using.

[`Selenium::WebDriver::Remote`](https://github.com/watir/watir/blob/e8dd0c2104c2ac2d5c22c31053792ee50b704215/lib/watir/capabilities.rb#L57) is something to investigate.